# Smallest number whose set bits are MINIMUM in a given range

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Given a positive integer ‘l‘ and ‘r‘. Find the smallest number ‘n‘ such that l <= n <= r and count of the number of set bits(number of ‘1’s in binary representation) is **MINIMUM** as possible.

This article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-number-whose-set-bits-maximum-given-range/ gives the smallest number with maximum set bits. But I need the smallest number in [l, r] with **minimum set bits**.

We can simply do this in linear time. But, I am looking for an Optimized Approach that accepts--

Time complexity: **O(log(n))**

Auxiliary space: **O(1)** or **O(n)**

**Constraints:**

1 <= l <= r <= 10^18

Below is my Code--

```
import math

l, r = map(int, input().split())
if l <= 2: print(l)
else:
    x1 = math.log(l, 2)
    x2 = math.log(r, 2)
    x3 = int(math.pow(2, math.ceil(x1)))
    
    if x1 == x2 or x3 > r:
       cnt = 32
       for i in range(l, r+1):
            s = bin(i).replace("0b", "")
            cnt1 = s.count('1')
            if cnt1 < cnt:
               cnt = cnt1
               ans = i
           
    else:
        ans = x3
        
    print(and)
```

I need to optimize the **for loop** in the above python code.
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun, here's a fast one-line solution (well, two lines including the `def`, but all the interesting stuff is in a single line) in Python. I'll unpack it a bit further down.

```py
def fewest_set_bits_obfuscated(l, h):
    return (h:=(l:=l-1)&-1<<(l^h).bit_length())|1<<(l^h).bit_length()
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> fewest_set_bits_obfuscated(617, 725)
640
```

Before we attempt to explain what's going on above, let's check that the code above does actually give the correct answer. Here's an obviously-correct but inefficient algorithm (though still a one-liner) to compute the first value with the smallest number of set bits in the range `[l, h]`. It makes use of the [`int.bit_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) method, which is new in Python 3.10:

```py
def fewest_set_bits_brute_force(l, h):
    return min(range(l, h+1), key=int.bit_count)
```

In case you don't have Python 3.10 available, here's an even slower version that counts the `1` bits manually:

```py
def fewest_set_bits_brute_force(l, h):
    return min(range(l, h+1), key=lambda n: bin(n).count("1"))
```

Now we can double check that `fewest_set_bits_obfuscated` and `fewest_set_bits_brute_force` give the same result for a range of inputs:

```py
MAX = 1000
for high in range(1, MAX+1):
    for low in range(1, high+1):
        ans_obfuscated = fewest_set_bits_obfuscated(low, high)
        ans_brute_force = fewest_set_bits_brute_force(low, high)
        assert ans_obfuscated == ans_brute_force, f"failed for {low}, {high}"
```

The above code will take a bit of time to run (around 41 seconds on my laptop), but it should complete without any of the `assert`s failing.

Now it's time to unpack the original one-line solution. First, let's rewrite that solution a bit:

```py
def fewest_set_bits_deobfuscated(low, high):
    low -= 1
    non_matching_length = (low ^ high).bit_length()
    common = low & (-1 << non_matching_length)
    match_low = low ^ common
    return common | 1 << match_low.bit_length()
```

Here we're performing exactly the same operations, in exactly the same order, as in the one-line version, but we've renamed the parameters, given names to some of the intermediate values, and unpacked the uses of the `:=` "walrus" operator.

The main idea here is that if you look at the binary expansions of `low` and `high`, there's some initial portion of those binary expansions that matches; after that initial portion, the expansions diverge. Our result must start with that same initial portion that `low` and `high` have, and then we can simply fill in the rest by adding just one more `1` bit in the right position.

For example, if `low=1641` and `high=1749` then the binary expansions are `0b11001101001` and `0b11011010101`. The common initial portion consists of  the first (i.e. most significant) three bits: `110`. After those first three bits, the next bit for `low` is a `0`, and the next bit for `high` is a `1`.
Every integer between `low` and `high` must also start with `110`, in that same position, and the number we're after is `0b11010000000`, or `1664`.

The first three lines of the function above find the common portion, `0b11000000000`, or `1536` in decimal. `low ^ high` finds the bits that *don't* match between `low` and `high`, then the `bit_length()` call tells us the length of the non-matching portion (which I'll also call the trailing portion). Then `-1 << non_matching_length` gives us a mask that can be used to extract the matching portion (`common`).

For the remaining bits, we simply want to replace the trailing portion of `low` (which is `match_low` in the function) with the next higher power of two, and that's what `1 << match_low.bit_length()` gives.

The above isn't *quite* right, because what we actually want to do is find the next power of two that's larger than or *equal to* the trailing portion of `low`. But it turns out to be slightly easier to compute the next power of two that's *strictly* larger than the trailing portion of `low`. Because of this, we compensate right at the beginning of the function by decrementing `low`, so that we're actually looking for a solution in the half-open interval `(low, high]`.

Comment: Your Solution is Accepted! The explanation you gave is also very understandable. Thank You for your answer.

Comment: @SagarSikchi: Thank you! Please do note that on Stack Overflow you can only accept one answer, so by accepting this one you unaccepted user1984's answer. I won't object in the slightest if you want to reverse that decision.

Comment: Your answer and user1984's answer are correct and acceptable. I applied the user1984's answer to the question for which I was looking for a solution and unfortunately, it didn't pass all cases. But the logic of user1984 was very appreciable. When I applied your answer, it got accepted and your logic was also correct. Because your answer has been accepted, I right-click on your answer. The original problem is listed here: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/january-circuits-022/.

Comment: I am not a very expert programmer, but I would like to suggest @user1984 go through this original problem so that you can find out where you have to improve your answer. I wish you the best (user1984 and Mark Dickinson, both of you) for your future journey! Thank You.

Comment: haha thanks @SagarSikchi and Mark Dickinson. I'll read this answer and also the original question. I'm here to learn. It's always appreciated to get feedback and learn new things :D

Comment: Just read your code: I'm in awe of the beauty of it. I've learned more than a lesson. Thank you both for the knowledge and your humbility.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the idea of a logarithmic approach.

The main concept behind it is the following: To reduce the number of set bits in the binary representation of a number while you can increase it up to an upper bound you must add a number equal to the value of the least significant set bit to the original number. This operation pushes the set bit to the left. When 2 set bits become adjacent, adding the value equal to the least significant bit effectively reduces the 2 set bits into one set bit while pushing it to the left.

```
given 01100
add   00100
gives 10000

another example:
given 00101
add   00001
gives 00110
add   00010
gives 01000
```

The above concept motivates the following algorithm:

```
def num_of_set_bits(num):
  res = 0
  while num:
    res += 1
    num = (num - 1) & num
  return res

def min_set_bits(low, high):
  res = num_of_set_bits(low)

  while low < high:
    low += (low & -low) # two's complement; unsets all except for the LSB
    if low <= high:
      res = min(res, num_of_set_bits(low))
  return res
```

Time complexity: O(log high * num of max set bits)
Space complexity: O(1)

There are some optimizations that can be done to the algorithm. For instance, if the number of set bits of low is 1, just return one. Or, we can look to the left of the LSB and if that bit is not set, we won't count the bits again since the operation won't reduce the number of bits. A further optimization is to reduce the number of bits by one automatically when we see that th left bit of LSB is set. We don't to count the number of bits any more. This reduces the Time complexity effectively to `O(log high)`.

**One note of caution at the end**: I'm not 100% sure about this algorithm since I havn't read it somewhere. I came up with it myself. I don't have a fully working proof but also no counter examples. Intuitively, it looks corrct to me but intuition has mislead me a lot of times. Any feedback or counter examples are appreciated.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed the part where you store the number when/if the number of bits is less. I was more concerned with the core algorithm and forgot about that. Do you need me to edit the answer to include that or do you think it's understandable as is? @SagarSikchi

Comment: No, the code is understandable. Let me share the original problem link, as I am unable to write my complete comment here due to words limit.

Comment: Link to Original Problem: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/january-circuits-022/algorithm/min-bits-3-1c87d621/

Comment: for l = 10001 and r = 11111, your code gives answer  as 10240 which is in range [l, r]. But the expected answer is 16384 which is out of range [l, r]. So, I think the question itself has some bugs (Incorrect Testcases). I think your code is correct. Thanks for this code.

Comment: You can raise a bug with them if you find incorrect test cases. BTW, if you find this answer helpful and/or if it answered your question, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. Thanks. @SagarSikchi

Comment: My reputation is 11 and I need at least 15 reputations to give my vote to answer. So, I am unable to upvote you.

Comment: When it will reach 15, I will gladly upvote your answer.

Comment: No problem, have a nice day @SagarSikchi Happy I could help. Also learned something myself today :D

Comment: Great work, @user1984 esp if you came up with this yourself. Nice observation on the fact that `adding 2's complement to a number will give next number with equal or lesser bits`. I think I read this as sometime in my college when I did competetive code. @SagarSikchi you should accept this answer (click the green tick below the voting triangles, only you must see that)

Comment: Thank you @vish4071 I'm humbled :D To be honest, I looked up the `(num & -num)` part that gives you the least significant set bit. I knew about it but couldn't remember it. But the idea of adding the LSB to num to reduce the number of set bits while increasing the number was my own, which I was unsure about. Thank you again for the encouraging words.